# Connecting zeromq sockets to redis server for data transfer?

Tags: sockets, redis, client-server, zeromq

I want to transfer messages, coming on server( A ZMQ_ROUTER socket, handling multiple clients) to redis server for storage purposes. I have heard that, redis doesn't speak ZMQ. So it cannot be possible without making a bridge. I am open to your suggestion. Where to look upon?

//Load Balanced Multithread-ed Server:

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <queue>
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "datamsg.pb.h"
using namespace google::protobuf::io;
  bool verify(std::string str, std::vector<std::string> &s)
  {
  for(int q=0;q<s.size();q++)
  {    
   if(s.at(q)==str.substr(0,4)){ 
   s.push_back(str.substr(4,str.length()-1));

  return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
 // Basic request-reply client using REQ socket
 static void * worker_thread(void *arg) {
  zmq::context_t context(1);
  zmq::message_t worker_receive;
  datamsg worker_parsed;
  zmq::socket_t worker(context, ZMQ_REQ);
  s_set_id(worker); // Makes tracing easier
  worker.connect("ipc://backend.ipc");
   // Tell backend we're ready for work
   s_send(worker, "READY");

   while (1) {
   // Read and save all frames until we get an empty frame
   worker.recv(&worker_receive);
   worker_parsed.ParseFromArray(worker_receive.data(), worker_receive.size());
  // printing after parsing......... 
   s_sendmore (worker, worker_parsed.destination());
   s_sendmore (worker, "");  
   worker.send(worker_receive);// Here I sent the same structure back
 }
 return (NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

// Prepare our context and sockets
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t frontend (context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
zmq::socket_t backend (context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
zmq::socket_t verification (context, ZMQ_REP);
verification.bind("tcp://*:5557");
std::vector<std::string> s;
s.reserve(10);
s.push_back("cli4");
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559");
backend.bind("ipc://backend.ipc");
zmq::message_t frontend_received; 
zmq::message_t front_get;
int worker_nbr;
 for(worker_nbr = 0; worker_nbr < 3; worker_nbr++) {
 pthread_t worker;
 pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_thread, NULL);
 }
 std::queue<std::string> worker_queue;

 while (1) {
  // Initialize poll set
   zmq::pollitem_t items[] = {
  // Always poll for worker activity on backend
  { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
  // Poll front-end only if we have available workers
  { frontend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
  //Poll for new customer for verification of client refrence ID
  {verification,0,ZMQ_POLLIN,0 }
}; zmq::poll (items, 3, -1);

if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {   // Handle worker activity on backend
// Queue worker address for LoadBalanced routing
   worker_queue.push(s_recv (backend));

// Second frame is empty
 std::string empty = s_recv (backend);
 assert (empty.size() == 0);

// Third frame is READY or else a client reply address
 std::string client_addr = s_recv (backend);
// If client reply, send rest back to frontend
if(client_addr.compare("READY") != 0) {   
  std::string empty = s_recv (backend);
  assert (empty.size() == 0);
  backend.recv(&frontend_received);
  s_sendmore (frontend, client_addr);
  s_sendmore (frontend, "");
  frontend.send(frontend_received);
  //frontend.close();
  }
}
if (items [1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
// Client request is [address][request]

 std::string client_addr = s_recv (frontend);

 frontend.recv(&front_get);
 std::string worker_addr = worker_queue.front();
 worker_queue.pop();

  s_sendmore (backend, worker_addr);
  s_sendmore (backend, "");
  backend.send(front_get);

}
if (items [2].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
 std::string refrence=s_recv(verification);
  if(verify(refrence,s)){
   s_send(verification,"OK");
   std::cout<<"ID:"<<refrence.substr(4,(refrence.length()-1))<<" Has been Registered"  <<std::endl;
 }
else s_send(verification,"Verification Failed!");
  }

}
sleep (1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apache Camel is a great project to build buses between different protocols.

Comment: Why does your application need to use ZMQ, as opposed to talking directly to redis with a redis module/library/etc?  If the redis server is on another host that you need to send the data to first by some means, typically you would write a client application for that host, that would then talk to redis natively.

Comment: @Jason I need to log all the messsages through redis server. Both zmq and redis are running natively (localhost) But I could not find a way to communicate to redis from zmq socket.? Do I need to write a separate client?

Comment: I reread your question, and now it makes a little more sense. I'll answer with how I would handle your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have an application running a ZMQ `ROUTER` socket, and you want to archive those messages to redis? Unless you have some constraint that you haven't mentioned, you should connect to redis directly from within your application, rather than trying to pass all communication through ZMQ.  ZMQ sockets only *ever* talk to other ZMQ sockets (without more or less reverse engineering the ZMQ protocol, but this would amount to building a bridge, which you said you don't want).

Redis has no native ZMQ connection option.

More or less what you'll need to accomplish will look like this:

```
-------Application-------      ------------
|                       |      | External |
|           ZMQ socket-(|<----(|  Source  |
|            v          |      ------------
|            V          |
|     (Process Data)    |      ----------
|            V          |      |  Redis |
|      Redis connector--|)---->| Server |
|                       |      ----------
-------------------------
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  If you provide code in your original question then we can address that directly.

Comment: @Jason Actually My application is entirely based on zeromq. Its a chat server with multiple sockets. Clients connect to it for instant messaging. I want to transfer messages from zmq sockets to redis. So bypassing zeromq is not an option(At-least I don't know). What do you mean by Redis connector. What kind of connector is this? kind of socket?. I have pasted all the code if you want to review, please do happily and thanks a lot for helping through visualizing :) +1

Comment: Your application is written in some language (I'm guessing Python, but you don't specify). That language has bindings which allow you to create a ZMQ socket and connect it to remote ZMQ sockets. That language also has *separate* bindings which allow you to connect to and send data to redis.

Comment: @Jason I am using C++. Its good to hear from you that its possible by using language binding. I will really happy to dig into that. Can you please tell me where to start, where to look upon

Comment: Check http://redis.io/clients, in particular the redis3m client appears to have some examples you can follow.  I can assume you want to log these messages to redis from your broker, so you'll add the logging code sometime after you receive the message and before you enter the next loop iteration.  This doesn't look much like a chat server yet, since you've got a front end and a back end, whereas I would think a chat server would be all front end.  I assume so far you've mostly copied the example code, which is fine... but make sure you understand your architecture.

Comment: @Jason Infact its a totally frontend chat server. I am using protocol buffers that,s why I am using backend threads to DEserialize and extract the destination IDs. So backend send packets back to frontend with destination. I am doing this to reduce the overhead on frontend of parsing and deserializing. :) Still I have started zmq a week ago. I am learning to use it. you are right! my code is greatly inspired by the example. Thanks for your help Jason. I really owe you. I am now looking on redis clients. thanks a lot